# Multiline Edit Box value into HTML to be sent in email in xpages

Tags: html, xpages

I found some great javascript code(xpHTMLMail file) to be able to create an HTML e-mail that the users create on the fly from an xpage document that they write a review on a salesperson.  However, there are some Multiline edit boxes on there and they have carriage returns, spaces, etc in them.  These do not come over when they are added to the HTML.  Anything I can do to keep the formatting for the e-mail that is created?  Thanks in advance.

Here's the code that deals with this part of my question(inputClosing is a Multiline Edit Box):

```
mail.addHTML("<br /><br /><b>Closing</b><br />"+getComponent('inputClosing').getValue())
```

If inputClosing has...

"Dear Joe,

Great work.  Keep it up!

Thanks,
Bill"

It comes into the email as...

Dear Joe, Great Work. Keep it up! Thanks, Bill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote that library so thanks!

Since you're creating an HTML mail, you need to replace the line breaks in the value of the Multiline Edit Box by `<br />` tags. Since you're dealing with Java in XPages, the line breaks are stored in the value using the `\r\n` sequence.

You can replace them using the the **replaceAll()** or (SSJS) **@ReplaceSubstring()** function.

Your code might then look like this:

```
var content:string = getComponent("inputClosing").getValue();   
mail.addHTML("<b>Closing</b><br />" + content.replaceAll("\r\n", "<br />") );
```

Comment: Mark, thanks for the awesome library!!  I used the <pre> and </pre> tags from another answer and they work great.  But your answer will help in some other things that I am doing so thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Mark's suggestion definitely works, but it might be easier just to wrap the text fields with `<pre></pre>` then it will treat them as text instead of html, no matter what kind of formatting character is in it.

Comment: Thanks for this tip as it worked perfectly.  I guess it's a pretty easy solution for someone with HTML knowledge.  I am finding it really stinks to have all this Notes Client-side programming knowledge and it seems not a lick of web skills.  I am sure it will click for me soon and I'll be able to answer someone's question down the road ;)